# What is the earliest moment in the game where I can kill Phineas Welles?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

Even though Welles revived me from my eternal slumber, I do not like him in the least and I want to kill him as soon as possible.

What is the earliest moment in the game where I can kill Phineas Vernon Welles?

I was hoping for his lab but unfortunately he locked himself in a room made of bulletproof glass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phineas is the *one* person you cannot directly kill in the game. That's exactly why the game designers have put him in the lab, Phineas is the catalyst of the main story (whichever way you go) and the main story would stall without him.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to kill Welles.

> You can kill him as the last enemy of the game if you side with the Board. Take the quests to turn him in, starting with the board representative on the Groundbreaker. The plot will proceed similar to the normal game, but Welles will be the last fight.

Comment: Is this the only moment in the game where I can off him?

Comment: Yes. The game specifically keeps him safe through narrative shenanigans, as @Flater states. It's just there is a point where he can be killed if you pursue a specific narrative path.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you can kill him relatively early, I glitched through the glass to attack him, not fully through just kept swinging my axe at him and jumping and managed to off him.